# What's the use of decltype when auto is already used for return type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I found this code in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

It has a template function declaration as:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u) {
    return t+u;
}
```

Since we already use `auto` here, I don't understand why it uses `decltype` again. I tried to remove `decltype` and it runs completely fine. Is this just redundant?

Comment: It is trailing return type, not auto deduction. (as for `auto main() -> int`), so unrelated to `decltype`.

Comment: You compiled as C++14 at least, not as C++11.

Comment: Without trailing return type, it would be: `template<typename T, typename U>
decltype(std::declvat<T>() + std::declvat<U>()) add(T t, U u)`

Comment: In this particular case,  the `auto` keyword has the job of a `func` keyword.